# pam_mount to mount ecryptfs-encrypted folder at login

Tags: automounting, ecryptfs

My system has encrypted home by using ecryptfs-utils.  I try to use pam_mount to mount a second encrypted folder, which has the same password, at login.

After installing pam-mount package from MXlinux repo:
`$ grep "pam_mount" /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:auth optional    pam_mount.so
/etc/pam.d/common-session:session   optional    pam_mount.so`

New pam_mount.conf.xml volume entry: (have tried many variations)
 `<volume
        noroot="1"
        fstype="ecryptfs" 
        path="/media/MAIN/.secret"
        mountpoint="/media/MAIN/secret" 
options="ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=a8d8ac8a4af02374,ecryptfs_sig=a8d8ac8a4af02374,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs" />`

auth.log reports "mount of /media/MAIN/.secret failed", nothing I recognize as a clue to why it failed.  (debug enable="1").  In auth.log I have:
`lightdm: command: 'mount' '-t' 'ecryptfs' '/media/MAIN/.secret' '/media/MAIN/secret' '-o' 'ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=a8d8ac8a4af02374,ecryptfs_sig=a8d8ac8a4af02374,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs'`
That appears to be the right command since if it is run from command line, it mounts the folder without requiring interaction apart from entering passphrase.

What am I doing wrong?

I guessed that maybe pam_mount is not receiving the login password, so I tried mounting an ecryptfs volume with a keyfile.
`options="ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=762365792a59155d,ecryptfs_sig=762365792a59155d,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=~/.keyfile.txt" />`

"Mount failed" appears several times in the auth.log file, but the folder is eventually mounted 1-25 minutes (!) after desktop appears. Why this weird behavior? Although keyfile is in the encrypted home folder, that is decrypted early on and it should be accessible -?-

Thanks in advance for explanations and suggestions.

Distro: MXLinux 18.3_x64.  "Systemd is included by default but not enabled."  sysvinit is default init, systemd-shim so "MX Linux can use Debian packages that have systemd dependencies..."

Comment: Could you trying formatting your question so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [simple way to mount an ecryptfs folder at login.](http://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=51830) using `mount.ecryptfs_private ALIAS` from ecryptfs-utils, not pam_mount.

@Paradox  I submitted an edit in response to your comment, but it got queued and never appeared.